# How do I validate height for format x'x"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regex that will verify whether the input string is in format 5'6" or not... thats all. i need to verify it in cs file (c#) not client side.

Comment: the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression:

```
      string height="5'6\"";

      Regex r = new Regex("^\\d+'\\d+\"$");
      Match m = r.Match(height);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            ' Yes!
      }
```

The regular expression **"^\\d+'\\d+\"$"** laid out:

- ^ = start of string
- \d+ = one or more numbers
- ' = character '
- \d+ = one or more numbers
- \" = character "
- $ = end of string

**Edit:** Added mandatory .Net escaping of backslash within "".

Comment: Hi i already have tried the above said one but i am getting error that Error 15 Unrecognized escape sequence If I use a @ synmbol still its not compilable. Please help me.

Comment: Use either `"^\\d+'\\d+\"$"` or `@"^\d+'\d""$"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex in which the second part is optional:

```
new Regex(@"^\d+'(\d+\")?$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean formatting a string ?

Look at string.format : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875(v=vs.71).aspx

Look at regex format : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Design a custom control like this guy did, you can fine tune his code to come up woth your own

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/39a071cd-9f96-4e81-9346-4e445181d645/aspnet-maskedtextbox-custom-control.aspx